# Run multiple shell scripts sequentially using the source command

Tags: bash, shell

I have a list of shell scripts which needs to be run sequentially and they take a different text file as input parameter. I tried to put all the scripts into a file and source the file.

But there is a bash error coming up. What is the best way to do this. My files are:

```
sh test.sh --dir hello --fname 1.txt --bdt 0318    
sh test.sh --dir hello --fname 2.txt --bdt 0318
```

Here dirname is the directory fname is filename.

Comment: What is the error  you are seeing?

Comment: bash: source: /usr/bin/test: cannot execute binary file

Comment: @Inian I included these scripts in a file test and running it as source test

Comment: Can you run it as `source ./test`

Comment: @Inian Its working. Thank you. But i ran the same with just the copy commands in a file and source run it. It worked. Why is not working for shell scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`source` command will](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins):

> Read and execute commands from the *filename* argument in the current shell context. If *filename* does not contain a slash, the `PATH` variable is used to find *filename*.

This behaviour [is defined (for `.`, its alias) by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot). So you can put sourceable configuration scripts inside `PATH` and access them without a qualified path. To access the file you want, give an absolute or relative path instead:

```
source ./test
```

Comment: @KattangooriReddy: You can do it, but as a background job it will not affect your running session.

Comment: @KattangooriReddy : there is nothing stopping it to work!  But it might not change the current shell's behavior.

Comment: The problem running on background is that I am connected to remote server through putty so it is disconnecting often and my session is expiring there by halting my source ./test